# New pandas columns based on another column IF statement

Tags: python, pandas

This is currently what I have and I want a new column where if the winner and prediction column both have a 1 then there will be a new column with the price.

| Price | Winner | Prediction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |

For example this is what I want:

| Price | Winner | Prediction | Return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 |

Comment: [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) can do this: `df['return'] = np.where((df['winner'] == 1) & (df['prediction'] == 1), df'[price'], 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution taking advantage of the boolean 0/1 equivalence:

```
df['Result'] = df[['Winner', 'Prediction']].sum(axis=1).eq(2).mul(df['Price'])
```

output:

```
   Price  Winner  Prediction  Result
0      2       0           1       0
1      4       1           1       4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.select`, and assign the values accordingly based on condition:

```py
>>> df.assign(Return=np.select([(df['Winner'].eq(1))&(df['Prediction'].eq(1))], [df['Price']], 0))

   Price  Winner  Prediction  Return
0      2       0           1       0
1      4       1           1       4
```